# Python open a JAR shortcut

Tags: python, jar

I have a JAR file saved on my desktop, is there a way that I ca get python to pen this up, as if I was just clicking on the link from my desk top, I am very new to python and know this is a dumb question, but would help me out alot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening a java JAR file from python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005300/opening-a-java-jar-file-from-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to execute it via Python?

In my Windows environment such `.jar` file is executed by Java:

```
C:\jre7\bin\javaw.exe -jar "%1" %*
```

Of course your OS should be able to change such association to open `.jar` with other program. On my Windows I can use local menu to open `.jar` file with Java, Eclipse, Firefox or I can chose other program.

Comment: I am just want to open an existing java shortcut and be able use it. All I am needing python to do it open the java shortcut. I haved used python in the past were I can in the morning use it to open all running programs I need such as excel files word and websites, now I am wondering if I can do the same with java?

Comment: I think you must read my answer to your similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005300/opening-a-java-jar-file-from-python

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using Windows (it seems that way from how you've presented the question).

To simulate double-clicking a file on Windows, use `os.startfile` (available only on Windows):

```
os.startfile("path/to/myjarfile.jar")
```

This will do whatever your system is configured to do with files with a `.jar` extension.

For a more complete answer on starting files on Windows see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435332/python-subprocess-module-equivalent-for-double-click-in-windows/4435373#4435373).